# Bash unexpected value of $0 inside script

Tags: bash, variables

I have two files `vars.sh` and `main.sh` with the contents:

```
$ cat vars.sh
#!/bin/bash
fname="$0"        # should $0 equal 'vars.sh'?

$ cat main.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
. vars.sh
echo $fname
```

When I run `main.sh`  I get:

```
$ ./main.sh
./main.sh
./main.sh
```

My question is why is `$0` inside `vars.sh` returning `main.sh`? I read `man bash` section about $0 but that did not help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sourcing another script involves executing the sourced commands in the *current* shell. In the current shell, `$0` refers to `main.sh`. You can think of sourcing as similar to "inclusion" or "copy-paste".

However, there does exist a way to get the sourced file name in bash. You can use `BASH_SOURCE` variable.

If you change `vars.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
```

Then you'll get the sourced file's name as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is because . (source) includes commands from sourced file, in your case from vars.sh

https://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Answer (score 2):

When a process is started via [exec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec), the first first argument is usually the path to the executable (or whatever the caller decided to pass there as argument). In bash, this argument can be retrieved via `$0`. In your case, your process is the bash process running `main.sh`, so that's what is stored there. `vars.sh` is executed within the same process; hence, `$0` is the same.